# How to set mail address for Unified Group in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm having a Microsoft Tenant with multiple domains assigned to it.

When I [create a group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups) I cannot specify the to be used domain. If I try by setting the mail property to a valid value `{mailNickName}@{domainAvailable}` the api returns an error:

> Code: Request_BadRequest
>   Message: Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set.

So how can I define which domain of a tenant should be used when creating a unified group through Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

The `mail` property is generated automatically. In order to populate it, you need to flip the `mailEnabled` bit:

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "mailEnabled": true
}
```

The mail property will then be automatically populated by Exchange Online using `mailNickname@default.domain`.

Comment: Yes, but how does Exchange decide which domain is the default and is there any possibility to influence this?

Comment: Office 365's Admin Portal has a [Domains](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/Domains) panel that allows the Admin to select the "default" domain from the list of previously added/verified domain names. The initial default is `{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com` but an Admin can add additional domains and select which one they want as the default. The rest just become aliases such that both `{name}@{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com` and `{name}@{custom.domain}` are valid but only one is surfaced as the user's `UPN`/`Mail`/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the behavior Marc describes. I have two domains in 365:

example.com (default)
example.onmicrosoft.com

When I create a group with mailEnabled set to true and provide a nickname, I get something like the following:

```
{
    "displayName": "Test Group",
    "groupTypes": ["Unified"],
    "mail": "test-group@example.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mailNickname": "test-group",
    "proxyAddresses": ["SMTP:test-group@example.onmicrosoft.com"],
    "securityEnabled": false,
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the domain will be choosen bei exchange. If a different should be pick, then you have to change the default with the powershell command [`Set-MsolDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoldomain). But it is not possible to select the domain on a per create request level.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind not being able to choose which of several valid domains to use when creating a group? It doesn't make sense to me.